# prefetch: EIP [00010000] > CS.limit [0000ffff] during second stage execution

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, osdev, bochs

I have created a simple bootloader with a second stage (kernel) loaded in memory at 0x1000:0x0000 which my bootloader starts executing with `jmp 0x1000:0000`. My bootloader is based upon the one in this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34092965/3857942)

My second stage/kernel is a simple command system.

The command system has only one command, i.e `"help"` (for now).  Everything works fine, but when I type the command `help`, I get the error in Bochs emulator:

```
[CPU0  ] prefetch: EIP [00010000] > CS.limit [0000ffff]
```

This is the code:

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x0000] 

mov ax, cs
mov ds, ax   
xor cx, cx  
mov bx, welcome_msg
call str_prt
call new_line
mov bx, creator_msg
call str_prt
call new_line
mov bx, boot_msg
call str_prt
call new_line
mov bx, [buffer]

mov ah, 0x0e
mov al, 0x0a
int 0x10
mov al, 0x0d
int 0x10
mov al, '>'
int 0x10

loop:
in al, 64h  
test al, 1    
je loop
xor ah, ah
int 0x16
call key_scan
jmp loop

key_scan:
cmp al, 0x08
je back_space
cmp al, 0x0d
je enter
cmp cx, 0x0041 
je end
mov ah, 0x0e
int 0x10
mov bx, buffer
add bx, cx
mov [bx], al
inc cx
jmp end
back_space:
cmp cx, 0x00
je end
dec cx
mov ah, 0x0e
mov al, 0x08
int 0x10
mov al, 0x20
int 0x10
mov al, 0x08
int 0x10
jmp end
enter:
xor cx, cx
mov ah, 0x0e
mov al, 0x0a
int 0x10
mov al, 0x0d
int 0x10
call pro_com
call clear_buffer
mov ah, 0x0e
mov al, '>'
int 0x10
end:
ret

str_prt:
pusha
str:
mov ah, 0x0e
mov al, [bx]
cmp al, '$'
je str_end
int 0x10
add bx, 1
jmp str
str_end:
popa
ret

new_line:
push ax
mov ah, 0x0e
mov al, 0x0a
int 0x10
mov al, 0x0d
int 0x10
pop ax
ret

clear_buffer:
push ax
push bx
push cx
mov bx, buffer
xor cx, cx
xor ax, ax
start:
cmp cx, 0x41
je end_buff
mov [bx], ax
inc bx
inc cx
jmp start
end_buff:
pop cx
pop bx
pop ax
ret

pro_com:
push bx
push ax
mov bx, buffer
mov al, [bx]
cmp al, 'h'
jne help_end
inc bx
mov al, [bx]
cmp al, 'e'
jne help_end
inc bx
mov al, [bx]
cmp al, 'l'
jne help_end
inc bx
mov al, [bx]
cmp al, 'p'
jne help_end
call com_help
jmp pro_end
help_end:
mov bx, not_found
call str_prt
call new_line
pro_end:
pop ax
pop bx
ret

com_help:
push bx
mov bx, help1_msg
call str_prt
call new_line
ret

buffer times 64 db 0

welcome_msg:
db 'Welcome to myOS$'
creator_msg:
db 'Created by Vishnu Shankar.B$'
boot_msg:
db 'Booting command line interface...$'
not_found:
db 'Command cannot be resolved!$'
help1_msg:
db 'Help not avilable!$'

jmp $
times 4096 - ($ - $$) db 0
```

Can somebody tell me what this means, and why it is occurring?

Comment: Wow, no comments on the code!

Comment: `com_help` has `push bx` but no `pop bx`.

Comment: I'm going to assume that this is the second stage of the bootloader you previously wrote that has been loaded at 0x1000:0x0000 (and you far jumped to it?)

Comment: I'd concur with @Jester that the `push bx` in *com_help*  doesn't have a corresponding `pop bx` . This will likely cause the program to return to the wrong address (CS:IP) when the `ret` is done and most likely cause a hang or crash.

Comment: @Michael Petch Yes, you are right! Adding the pop instruction fixed it!

Comment: Thanks to whoever edits my questions and make them better!

Comment: No problem. I amended your question based on my knowledge of your previous question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be a trivial one as Jester identified. In *com_help* you do this:

```
com_help:
    push bx
    mov bx, help1_msg
    call str_prt
    call new_line
    ret
```

You `push BX` on the stack but don't restore it with `pop BX` when finished. This will cause the `ret` instruction to pop the wrong return address off the stack and continue execution to a memory location you didn't intend to go to. This can cause a program to hang or even an emulator like *BOCHS* to throw a message depending on circumstances. The code should look like:

```
com_help:
    push bx
    mov bx, help1_msg
    call str_prt
    call new_line
    pop bx
    ret
```

Comment: I also marked it as Community Wiki since it was Jester's comment that was originally correct.