# How do I define and use variables in the bootsector with NASM?

Tags: variables, assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader

I have been playing around a bit with NASM assembly and directly working with the BIOS from the boot sector but I'm not able to define a variable like I'd usually do with NASM.

When I try to define and use a variable like usually

```
BALL_X dw 0x140
BALL_Y dw 0xF0

[...]

mov cx, [BALL_X]
mov dx, [BALL_Y]
```

it just doesn't seem to return/contain any value, though the assembler doesn't complain either when assembling it.
I've also tried it with and without the
`section .data` and `section .text` but that doesn't seem to change anything either.
The only way I've got it to work is by manually assigning a name to an address and then assigning the values separately

```
BALL_X equ $
BALL_Y equ $

[...]

mov word[BALL_X], 0x140
mov word[BALL_Y], 0xF0
```

I've been searching for a solution on the internet but I'm struggling to find anything about how to get this to work properly, as the second method seems like a bit of a hack to me.

In case the entire code snippet helps(of the last thing I tried):

```
mov word[BALL_X], 0x140
mov word[BALL_Y], 0xF0

main:
    mov ah, 0x00       ;Set video mode
    mov al, 0x12       ;640x480 16 color graphics
    int 0x10           ;Interrupt

    mov ah, 0x0B       ;Set background color
    mov bh, 0x00       ;Set background color
    mov bl, 0x00       ;Black
    int 0x10           ;Interrupt
    
    
    mov ah, 0x0C       ;Write pixel
    mov al, 0x0F       ;White
    mov bh, 0x00       ;Page number
    mov cx, [BALL_X]   ;X
    mov dx, [BALL_Y]   ;Y
    int 0x10           ;Interrupt
    
    jmp exit


exit:
    jmp $


BALL_X equ $
BALL_Y equ $

times 510-($-$$) db 0  ;padding
db 0x55, 0xAA          ;magic bytes to make it bootable
```

Comment: The first way with `dw` is correct.  `equ` is wrong as it defines a constant without reserving any memory, and you will end up with `BALL_X` and `BALL_Y` both pointing to the same address, so that your second `mov` overwrites the first.  So the question is why the `dw` version didn't work.  Please post that version of the code ([mcve]); it probably has some other bug.

Comment: Sections are pretty meaningless in a boot sector where you need a flat chunk of memory laid out in a particular order.  One common mistake is to locate your variables before the code, or somewhere else that's in the path of the code, so that they end up getting executed - any chance that's the issue?

Comment: When you say "it doesn't seem to contain any value" - that doesn't really make sense, memory always contains some value.  What is it that you actually observe?

Comment: Good practise also indicates to set up the segment registers before accessing memory. `xor ax, ax` \ `mov ds, ax` before any memory access achieves this.

Comment: Your example is missing the `org 7C00h` line too.

Comment: @ecm: The default `org` is `0` if you don't use an org directive, right?  So I think it's a duplicate of Michael Petch's nice long answer on [Reading from memory in 8086 real mode while using 'ORG 0x0000'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34411336) that describes what's going on.  (Except for the `equ` attempt!)

Comment: @ecm That seems to have fixed it, thank you!

Comment: @Peter Cordes: Yes, omitting the `org` is equivalent to setting it to zero. To be fair, you could do that and have it turn out correct if you initialised `ds` to 7C0h.

Comment: I've seen a few boot sector games that use the screen memory as a place to store variables.