# How to passthrough USB device through Qemu in Windows?

Tags: qemu

Trying to figure out how to pass through a USB stick into the Qemu environment. Anyone know??

Thanks

Comment: This worked for me https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Managing#Adding_USB_Device_Pass-through