# Qemu unable to load EDK2 Duet Image

Tags: qemu

I made a floppy disk image that has Duet package installed in there and I am trying to test it out with either Qemu or Bochs but unfortunately the boot process doesn't get farther than 'Welcome to Efi World!'. However it works just fine when it has been imaged directly onto a usb key so it is obviously an issue with these emulators address higher memory I suppose. I just don't know how to fix this or what config to feed Qemu or Bochs..

Thanks

FYI: Heres a link to the floppy image in question if anyone wants to try to get it going: http://www.mediafire.com/file/6dacunk29tm7muc/floppy.7z

Comment: Have you tried using the `-enable-kvm` option of QEMU?

Comment: And of course use  `qemu-system-x86_64`

Comment: Well I was never able to figure out how to use qemu to load a Duet Image but found that Virtualbox did it just fine by adding a floppy controller and pointing it to my floppy image file.

Comment: Made some more progress. Qemu will load my Duet image if the file size is 1440 KB. Anything smaller Qemu falters and the Bootloader doesn't progress to its second stage. Dont know why.